# A lot of sites are going to be 10 this year - could we do something to celebrate?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, community, stackexchange-2.0

Admittedly, the other site I mod is [11](https://youtu.be/KOO5S4vxi0o?t=7), and I embarrassingly missed the anniversary in the midst of a bunch of things. I had a mod go "My community is coming up on its 10 year anniversary, and I think SE should recognise that" in a private conversation. He kind of has a point, since these communities are those that form the foundation of the network. By a quick count 4 communities are over 11  - SO *did* have their 11th remembered, and MO's a bit of an unusual case but that leaves 2 of the original trilogy in 4 parts, Superuser and Server Fault. Nearly 30 sites are  between 10-11 with another 17 6 months from 10 years old.

These sites and their communities are the backbone of our network, and they're mature sites that  helped build up the network.

Are there any plans to help these sites celebrate their decade anniversary?

Comment: Another hat hunt? ;)

Comment: Maybe 10% discount for Teams? ;)

Comment: No actual fireworks, please. Virtual would be fine... hats, too.

Comment: Which sites? I love lists.

Comment: Yes! We will be discussing this in the coming days. We love that the communities continue to thrive and grow and we want to celebrate those anniversaries together. I should have more to share around October.

Comment: See also: [How should we celebrate 10 years of Ask Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19187/how-should-we-celebrate-10-years-of-ask-ubuntu), [Organising “classrooms” for 10th birthday celebrations](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19218/organising-classrooms-for-10th-birthday-celebrations) and [Creating a banner for 10th birthday celebrations](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19236/creating-a-banner-for-10th-birthday-celebrations) (I'm stuck on the last one as we need help from above)

Comment: For Server Fault, you could implement policies that encourage the previous heavy contributors to return to the site, because it has decayed so far that I no longer ask questions there, and for questions I can't ask on other SE sites, I ask places other than SE, and for several tools SE is now 3 or 4 place for the to ask a question.